# How can I loop over an array as many times as I want to?

Tags: php, arrays

I want to iterate over my array as many times as I want, so I get an output like this:

```
1 -> R
2 -> G
3 -> B
4 -> B
5 -> G
6 -> R
7 -> R
8 -> G
9 -> B
10 -> B
...

Till 100
```

So far I started with this code:

```
$range = range(1,100);
$color = array("Red", "Green", "Blue");
$clr = 0;
for($i=0; $i<count($range); $i++){

    echo "<div style='color :".$color[$clr]."'>".$range[$i]. " " .$color[$clr]. "<br>"; 
    $clr++;

    if($clr == 3){  
        $clr = 0;   
    }   
}
```

Comment: what you have tried post that ?

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking can you be more specific?

Comment: I want to run a look that reverse when $color==3

Comment: Thats not a PHP problem. And the title has nothing to do with what the author asked.

Comment: So where are we with this question? Did any of the answers below solved your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$range = range(1,100);

$color = array("Red", "Green", "Blue");

$clr = 0;
$check = 0;

for($i=0; $i<count($range); $i++){


    echo "<div style='color :".$color[$clr]."'>".$range[$i]. " " .$color[$clr]. "<br>";

    if($check==0){
  $clr++;
  }
  if($clr==0){
   $check=0;
  }
  if($clr>2){
   $check++;
  }
  if($check==1){
   $clr--;
  }

}
```

I did it

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

First add the reversed array to your array, which you get with [`array_reverse()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php). After this you have an array like this:

```
Array(
    [0] => Red
    [1] => Green
    [2] => Blue
    [3] => Blue
    [4] => Green
    [5] => Red
)
```

And then you can use an [`InfiniteIterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.infiniteiterator.php) to iterate over it as many times as you want, e.g.

```
<?php

    $limit = 100;
    $color = array("Red", "Green", "Blue");

    $arrayIt  = new ArrayIterator(array_merge($color, array_reverse($color)));
    $infiniteIt = new InfiniteIterator($arrayIt);
    $it    = new LimitIterator($infiniteIt, 0, $limit);

    foreach($it as $v)
        echo substr($v, 0, 1) . PHP_EOL;

?>
```

output:

```
R
G
B
B
G
R
//...
```